# NHibernate results are empty with ClassMap, but not with raw SQL

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, unit-of-work

I am setting up a project with NHibernate, and I have a problem.

When I try to do this:

```
public Person GetById(int id)
        {
            using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(_nHibernateFactory.GetFactory()))
            {
                var result = unitOfWork.CurrentSession.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM [TABLENAME]").List();

            }

        }
```

I get fine results, and I can query my data.

However, when I have this `ClassMap`:

```
 public class PersonMap:ClassMap<Person>
    {
        public PersonMap()
        {
            Table("TABLENAME");
            Id(p => p.Id);
            Map(p => p.Name);
        }
    }
```

And I run:

```
 public Person GetById(int id)
        {
            using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(_nHibernateFactory.GetFactory()))
            {
                var result = unitOfWork.CurrentSession.Query<Person>().ToList();
        }
```

Results are empty, despite they should look in the same table (I have cross checked table name is the same).

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try to watch actual query with sql-profiler?

Comment: @Backs unfortunately not, as I don't have sysadmin permissions :-)

Comment: You do not need sysadmin permissions to check actual sql query. You can use a tool like [NH Prof](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof) to do that

Comment: Have you added the mapping class to the nhibernate configuration? You need to tell nHibernate which mappings to use. see here: https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-configuration

Comment: @OrlandoHelmer You are right. Could you make an answer, so i can accept it? :-) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your mappings files to your Fluent nHibernate configuration. See here: https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-configuration